# Export to excel is not working while print the report

Tags: css, excel

After generating the Excel report, if I give print (CTRL + P) for the downloaded excel sheet, the last column is going on to the next page. How can I resolve this alignment issue.

Please find the below image.

[image]

And the last column is going on to the second page.

[image]

Please find this .[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jWAJ7/5112/)

```js
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding : 10px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Excel -> Page Layout -> Width -> 1 Page.

Comment: Yeah it is working. Is any other option is there to do using code.